# docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.24.2 not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Following this guide:
https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/

and both

```
export K8S_VERSION=$(curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)
```

and

```
export K8S_VERSION=$(curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/latest.txt)
```

fail at the `docker run`  stage with a `not found` error. E.g:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.24.2 not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "v1.24.2" from request "/v2/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64/manifests/v1.24.2".
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact the article author and ask them to fix the article with the correct docker image url

Comment: this article seems quite old, that google hypercube may be not available anymore, just look for a newer tutorial. similar issue if you wish https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33969

Comment: I recommend to have a look at minicube or k3s

Comment: @vladtkachuk or kind

Answer (score 0):

Check the repo of hyperkube and use an available tag:
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/global/hyperkube-amd64

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @zerkms @vladtkachuk that google hyperkube is not available anymore. As mentioned in the [document](https://www.stackrox.io/blog/what-s-new-in-kubernetes-1-19/):

> Hyperkube, an all-in-one binary for Kubernetes components, is now
> deprecated and will not be built by the Kubernetes project going
> forward.Several, older beta API versions are deprecated in 1.19 and
> will be removed in version 1.22. We will provide a follow-on update
> since this means 1.22 will likely end up being a breaking release for
> many end users.

Setting up a local Kubernetes environment as your development environment is the recommended option, no matter your situation, because this setup can create a safe and agile application-deployment process.

Fortunately, there are multiple platforms that you can try out to run Kubernetes locally, and they are all open source and available under the Apache 2.0 license.

**Minikube** has the primary goals of being the best tool for local Kubernetes application development, and to support all Kubernetes features that fit.

**kind** runs local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container "nodes."